# Entity Framework 5 and TPT design issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am doing code first and using a Table-per-type design. I am getting the following error when I extend the second object to multiple tables:

A value shared across entities or associations is generated in more than one location. Check that mapping does not split an EntityKey to multiple store-generated columns.

My database looks like:

Thanks for the up-vote, editing to add my picture:
[image]

The POCO for the project looks like:

```
public abstract class Project {
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocationElement> LocationElements { get; set; }


    public abstract string getProjectIdentifier();

}
```

And for a Location Element:

```
public enum HowObtainedCodes {
    Provided = 1,
    Estimated = 2,
    Summarized = 3
}
public abstract class LocationElement {
    public int LocationElementID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public HowObtainedCodes HowObtainedCodeID { get; set; }
}
```

And for a point:

```
[Table("ProvidedPoints")]
public class ProvidedPoint : LocationElement {
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The link from projects (abstract) to scientific licences works fine, and my objects load / persist as expected. Further I can add LocationElements object in if I make it not abstract. As soon as I extend LocationElements and try to save a ProvidedPoint object I get the above message. My first thought was that the LocationElementID on ProvidedPoints was set as an Identity column, but this was not the case.

My question is: Am I doing something unexpected by trying to link two TPT objects together in this way? Am I missing something else?

Comment: There! Upvoted! Maybe you can post an image now ﾂ

Comment: I dont know EF, but it seems you should decorate your abstract class (`LocationElement`), else how would it know the table?

Comment: What I wrote before I tried your suggestion: I believe it follows the naming convention for mappings (i.e. LocationElement will auto map to LocationElements unless told otherwise. I believe you only need to do this in the sub-classes, as it is working for the project object with out the annotation.


What I wrote after I tried it to be certain: Holy (&*^*^#, that was it!

Comment: Can I mark a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @leppie above, I had to decorate the LocationElement class with the annotation [Table("LocationElements")], which immediately fixed the problem. My understanding with EF was that this was not necessary with the base table for a TPT design, and further I had not done it on the Project / ScientificLicence pair (that is, I only decorated the ScientificLicence object).

I am assuming this has something to do with the way LocationElements are added/persisted when I save a new Project object. If anyone has any additional insight I would love to know more.

Hope this helps someone else and a big thank you to leppie!